# How to add applink to custom story via Object Browser? (hosted object)

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to post custom story with applink. I have defined action type **complete** and an object **step** - so user can **"complete a step"** inside app. Then I defined one step using Object Browser. How can I add applink via Object Browser?

There is a field `al:android`, which I assume needs to be filled with data. There is a hint stating that I should put there JSON object or array. So I did.

**Tried with:**

```
{"package":"com.example.myapp","class":"com.example.myapp.MainActivity","app_name":"My Example App"}
```

**I've got error:**

[image]

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Facebook Mobile Hosting API to create App Link objects. Here is documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api

Should get in return something like this: `{"id":"643402985734299"}`, this is the ID of hosted applink - try with it.